# mapping target ignore doesn't work with nested one to many relation and circular dependency lists, Spring boot Mapstruct returns stackoverflow error

Tags: java, spring-boot, circular-dependency, mapstruct

I am using spring boot and mapstruct 1.5.1

I have 4 layer one to many relations in the structure and I'm trying map whole structure. However, at the bottom (last) layer I am getting stackoverflow exception because of circular dependency. I tried ignore with @Mapping annotation and pointed last layers circle but it didn't work.

Here is my whole object tree, when i try to add the document related with document type it's throwing an error. I used ignore before in more basic relations and it worked but now i can't figurate how to solve this error.

project 1----->n documentClass 1----->n documentType 1-----> document

I'm tying map project entity to projectDto

here is how i'm using ignore in @Mapping annotation :

`@Mapping(target="documentClasses.documentTypes.documents.documentType" ignore=true)`
[@Mapping annotation usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lojTR.png)
I broke the documents relation to take picture of instance
[Project entity instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ7j2.png)
If i add the document relation this happens
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3688.jpg)
And also following photo belong to project entity instance with document
[project entity instance with document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV45Y.jpg) 
I also added @EqualsAndHashCode annotation into entities it was working until i added document class into relations.
this is how i used @EqualsAndHashCode

`@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, exclude= "documentType")`
[Document Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZOgB.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `CycleAvoidingMappingContext` and disable the `builder` usage for mapstruct. `@Mapper(builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))`

This will reuse the previously instantiated implementation upon mapping it the second time and not enter the actual mapping process again. This however will only work with `setters` and it will not work if you are using `builders` or `complete field assignment through constructor`. With those last 2 methods the mapping of the fields takes place before the construction of the object. Thus for breaking the cycle it will not have access to a previously instantiated value and therefor still end up in a `StackOverflowException`.

You can find an example at the mapstruct example repository:

- https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/main/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles/

Check these stackoverflow questions and answers for more information about different ways to solve issues with cycles:

- [Mapping objects with bi-directional relations with Mapstruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646904/mapping-objects-with-bi-directional-relations-with-mapstruct)
- [How to Map an object contains other object with @oneToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924232/how-to-map-an-object-contains-other-object-with-onetomany)

In case you want to break the cycle in the resulting structure:

- [How to avoid cyclic dependency when using MapStruct and converting collections (List)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761563/how-to-avoid-cyclic-dependency-when-using-mapstruct-and-converting-collections)